# Running python script after 2-5 times (random) gives me error (will work again if I restart the django server!)

Tags: python, django, pafy

let's say I created a basic web for converting youtube videos to gifs

this is my views in django code

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
import pafy
from PIL import Image
from moviepy.editor import *
import os

context = RequestContext(request)
    if request.GET:
        link = request.GET.get('link','')
    url = link
    try:
        video = pafy.new(url)
    except:
        return render_to_response("generated/invalid.html", context)
    video = video.getbest()
    if os.path.isfile(os.getcwd()+'\\static\\'+video.title+'.gif')==True:
        gifpath=video.title+'.gif'
        context_dict = {'staticpath':gifpath}
        return render_to_response("generated/generated.html", context_dict, context)
    video.download(quiet=True)
    clip = (VideoFileClip(os.getcwd()+"\\"+video.title+'.'+video.extension).resize(0.4))
    clip.write_gif(os.getcwd()+'\\static\\'+video.title+'.gif', fps=9, opt='optimizeplus', loop=0)
    gifpath=video.title+'.gif'
    context_dict = {'staticpath':gifpath}
    return render_to_response("generated/generated.html", context_dict, context)
```

it works fine, but after I convert 2-5 videos (it's random) it gives me this error,
[image]
from the looks of it, the cause is in the VideoFileClip method AttributeError
It will works again if I restart the django server, strange!!!

in the django debugger, the exception is [WinError 6] The handle is invalid
[image: 2]

Tried it with windows 8.1 64 bit and windows 7 32 bit

UPDATE, I think it's the gif converter causing this, after I turned on the downloading status pafy confirmed I downloaded the video (look at uppest and lowest request)
[image]

but what makes it strange is that, the error pops out after running it random times. Do you think it's my code's fault or the lib?

Comment: hmmm ok, previous comments don't apply then, deleted. It's interesting that the error is in the VideoFileClip.__del__ function. To me that would indicate that the library has a problem, but then it's Python and very easy for us as developers to manipulate an object to cause an error so without all your code I couldn't say for sure.

Comment: @Endophage thanks, I'm contacting the library dev now. But what makes it strange is that it will only works after I restart the django server. Sorry, what do you mean all of my code? I only have 2 django apps and they are not sharing var or connected by any means

Comment: If you have some logic path that ends up doing something with the reader attribute on the VideoFileClip instance it could cause this error. What I meant was without crawling through all your code I couldn't tell you whether that's the problem. Note it also says `Exception ignored`. Have a read of the \_\_del__ docs, especially the red box https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__